# Find matching rows in a numpy matrix of 3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, cube

Given a cube of mxmxm, I need to know the rows, in the 6 faces that the smallest value in their row is greater than a given n.

Comment: Some combination of `np.min`, `>` and `[]`, repeat this 6 times for different axes.

Comment: Errr... what orientation are your "rows" in? There's no canonical basis that indicates the direction here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To obtain the various faces:

```
faces = np.array([
    x[ 0,  :,  :],
    x[-1,  :,  :],
    x[ :,  0,  :],
    x[ :, -1,  :],
    x[ :,  :,  0],
    x[ :,  :, -1],
])
```

Now collapse the last dimension axis:

```
# No information on orientation provided by OP so always pick axis=-1
row_mins = np.min(faces, axis=-1)
```

And then keep only the rows that satisfy the condition:

```
valid_rows = faces[row_mins > n]
print(valid_rows)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can filter the values with the help of iteration. For [numpy iteration](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_iterating.asp)

[image: code_image]

**codes**

```
import numpy as np
data=np.arange(54).reshape(6,3,3)
print(data,data.ndim)

#n : given value to filter
n=10

#to get all the elements that are greater than n
print(data[data>n])

for i in data:
  for row in i:
    if  row[row>n].size :
        print(row)
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.